# REST Assured Multiple values for query param not working

Tags: java, rest-assured

only plan block is coming in response but for productId filter not working in Rest assured.
The same is working in postman

Code to get response rest assured

```
Response response = RestAssured
                .given()
                .baseUri(baseUri)
                .header("content-type", "application/json")
                .cookies("SESSIONID", cookie)
                .get("api/members/"
                        + 1
                        + "/search?expand=plan,product");
```

Answer (score 5):

Please give like this , It's tested and working and kindly amend as per your URI

@Test(enabled=true)

```
    public  void performMultipleQueryparametrs() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://reqres.in/";
        RestAssured.basePath = "api/";
        given().urlEncodingEnabled(false).contentType(ContentType.JSON). with().queryParam("page", 2).queryParam("id", 9).
        when().get("users").then().statusCode(200).log().all();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but as you see in my question the query param is having multiple values seperated by comma that is not working

Comment: Then you need to handle special character .String paraVal= "plan,product";given().urlEncodingEnabled(true).contentType(ContentType.JSON). with().queryParam("key",paraVal)
         when().get("").then().statusCode(200).log().all();

Comment: Thank you @SameeraDeSilva , by adding  urlEncodingEnabled(false) it worked

Comment: urlEncodingEnabled(false). 
thanks for this.