# How to handle multiple path parameters in RestAssured?

Tags: java, rest-assured

We have a restAssured GET call:

```
 public Response getRequest( final int survey_ID){
    httpRequest.header("Content-Type", ContentType.JSON);
    httpRequest.header("Authorization", System.getProperty("apiKey"));
    httpRequest.pathParams("survey_id", survey_ID);
    return httpRequest.get("/{survey_id}");
}
```

Now there's new end-point which accepts multiple path parms like:

```
 goals/check-enabled?survey_ids=54321,12345
```

[Here Survey_ids could be 1 or many]

So, how could I handle this in my code?
I was thinking to implement something like below, but I suppose there could be a better way.

```
  public Response getRequest( final int[] survey_IDs){
    httpRequest.header("Content-Type", ContentType.JSON);
    httpRequest.header("Authorization", 
    System.getProperty("apiKey"));
//        another Option
//        for(int survey_ID : survey_IDs){
//            httpRequest.pathParams("survey_id", survey_ID);
//        }
        return httpRequest.get("/{survey_ids}", survey_IDs);
    }
```

Please suggest

Thanks a lot

Comment: What's wrong with this approach? You can use `forEach` method to save 1-2 lines of code.

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 Its not a query about `forEach` but I would like to know generally how multiple path parameters are handled using RestAssured, do you have a sample code? Thanks

Comment: Your new endpoint requires a query param, not a path param. Then this may work `.queryParam("survey_ids", asList(54321, 12345))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL example you give in the question, i.e., `goals/check-enabled?survey_ids=54321,12345` shows `survey_ids` being a `query` parameter, **not** `path` parameter as you describe. A path parameter would be something like this: `/items/{item_id}`, where you need to pass the item id, for example, `/items/2`. Maybe you could try something like the below, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60051595), for passing multiple values for a query parameter (which seems to be what you are looking for).

```
String survey_IDs= "54321,12345";
RestAssured.given().urlEncodingEnabled(false).
    contentType(ContentType.JSON).with().
    queryParam("survey_ids", survey_IDs).
    when().get("").then().statusCode(200).log().all();
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are having exactly ONE query parameter (because of the `?param=value` syntax) even if it looks like a path parameter with a list.

You can choose between these options:

1. Specify a multi-value query parameter that'll be sent with the request e.g:

```
...given().queryParam("survey_ids", asList("54321", "12345"))...;
```

This will set the parameter survey_ids=54321 and survey_ids=12345

The method needs to be adjusted this way:

```
public Response getRequest(List<Integer> survey_IDs) {
```

2. Stay using one query parameter but split it.

```
String[] ids = survey_IDs.split(",");
```

```
...given().queryParam("survey_ids", "54321,12345")...;
```